# mdadm assembling array issues

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

My motherboard died, so I had to replace it, including the OS.

So I boot first time, do mdadm --assemble --scan, raid assembled without any issues. I share the drive, reboot.

Then it stops recognizing it.

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : inactive sdb[4](S)
      1953511512 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

The disks are as follows (sdb, sdc, sdd):
[image]

Why did it work the first time, then stopped working all of a sudden?

If I try to force them, it doesnt work:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md127 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdb is busy - skipping
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: /dev/sdc has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to figure out what's wrong.  Could you post the results of `mdadm --examine /dev/sd{b,c,d}`, `mdadm --detail /dev/md127`, and `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`, `smartctl -a /dev/sdc`, and `smartctl -a /dev/sdd`?

Comment: It's gone, I had to reformat, recreate from scratch...